# Is there a version of this code supported by IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I was just wondering how to get this code working on IE11 to return the current cursor position in a text field:

```
getCursorPosition: function() {
  var s, e, r;
  if(this.inputTextElement.createTextRange){
     r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
     r.moveEnd('character', this.inputTextElement.value.length);
     if(r.text === ''){
        s = this.inputTextElement.value.length;
     } else {
        s = this.inputTextElement.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
     }
     r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
     r.moveStart('character', -this.inputTextElement.value.length);
     e = r.text.length;
  } else {
     s = this.inputTextElement.selectionStart;
     e = this.inputTextElement.selectionEnd;
  }
  return this.CursorPosition(s, e, r, this.inputTextElement.value);
},
```

Comment: Have you figured out what part of it doesn't work?

Comment: IE11 runs the first if statement, and then returns an error at     document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
document.selection isn't supported in IE11, but I can't figure out how to get the same type of object using window.getSelection();

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    getCursorPosition: function () {
    var s, e, r;
    if (this.inputTextElement.getSelection) {
        r = document.getSelection();
        if (r.text === '') {
            s = this.inputTextElement.value.length;
        } else {
            s = this.inputTextElement.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
        }
        e = r.focusOffset.toString();
    } else {
        s = this.inputTextElement.selectionStart;
        e = this.inputTextElement.selectionEnd;
    }
    return this.CursorPosition(s, e, r, this.inputTextElement.value);
},
```

Also change the function bellow

```
moveCursorToPosition : function(keycode, cursorPosition) {
    var p = (!keycode || (keycode && keycode.isBackspace ))? cursorPosition.start: cursorPosition.start + 1;
    if (this.inputTextElement.getSelection) {
        cursorPosition.range.move('character', p);
        cursorPosition.range.select();
    } else {
        this.inputTextElement.selectionStart = p;
        this.inputTextElement.selectionEnd = p;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently IE11 doesn't support the first part (first if statement) but returns true on the if statement. My code now checks specifically for IE11 and makes sure that you aren't using IE11 in the first if statement. The second if statement runs fine.